# why is jquery video.trigger("play") firing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

i have an html5 video element that i would like to play on page load.
after each video play i want to add more code for different things.

for some reason the *.trigger("play")* makes the video play twice.
if i pause it and play again from the html controls it plays once.
I can't understand why the initial trigger makes the video play twice.
I only need it to run once.

html:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls >
<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

jquery:

```
    var triggerCount = 0;
    $("video").on("play", function () {
    console.log(++triggerCount);
//do more stuff here
    })

    $("video").trigger("play");
```

code example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gababa/369ovtmq/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not trigger these native events manually. Just use:

```
$("video")[0].play()
```

or for all videos

```
$("video").each((i,el) => el.play());
```

or better with autoplay attribute

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
```

Note that some browsers may prevent autoplay without user interaction..

Comment: thanks! your code seems to work. and also i have found a solution with pure java script, but just for learning purposes - what is the reason that it fires twice?

Comment: Because first you trigger it manually and second it is triggered by media element when it starts to play..